# Using Mollifiers

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution

If we take $f$ to be a smooth function, then how does it follow that we can write $f^{\epsilon}(x)-f(x) = \int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y)(f(x-\epsilon y)-f(x))dy$ where $f^{\epsilon} := \eta_{\epsilon}\ast f$ where $(\epsilon>0)$ and

$\eta_{\epsilon}$ denotes the usual mollifier.

Comment: $RHS=\int \eta (y)f(x-\epsilon y) dy- f(x) \int \eta (y) dy = \int \frac{\eta(y/ \epsilon)}{\epsilon} f(x-y) dy - f(x) = LHS$

Comment: If further work shows that $f^{\epsilon}(x)-f(x) = - \epsilon \int_{B(0,1)} \eta(y) \int_{0}^{1}Df(x-\epsilon t y)\cdot y dtdy$

Then it follows that: $\int_{V}|f^{\epsilon}(x)-f(x)|dx \leq \epsilon \int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y) \int_{0}^{1}\int_{V}|Df(x-\epsilon t y)|dxdtdy \leq \epsilon \int_{V}|Df(z)|dz$. 

Can you see how the last inequality follows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part (by Tim kinsella): 
$$RHS=\int \eta (y)f(x-\epsilon y) dy- f(x) \int \eta (y) dy = \int \frac{\eta(y/ \epsilon)}{\epsilon} f(x-y) dy - f(x) = LHS$$
Answering follow-up question: if $V$ is the entire space, then for any $t,y$
$$  \int_{V}|Df(x-\epsilon t y)|dx =   \int_{V}|Df(x )|\,dx  $$
Subsequent integration in $t$ and $y$ yields $1$.

Comment: Thanks for response. By your argument do we actually get equality by: $\epsilon \int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y)\int_{0}^{1}\int_{V}|Du_{m}(x-\epsilon ty)|dxdtdy = \epsilon\int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y)dy\int_{0}^{1}dt\int_{V}|Du_{m}(x)|dx = \epsilon(1)(1)\int_{V}|Du_{m}(x)|dx$  ?

Comment: I have one question about Tim Kinsella's part. If we consider the first term of the RHS: $\int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y)u_{m}(x-\epsilon y)dy$ then using change of variable $z= \epsilon y$ we get the determinant of the Jacobian: $|\text{det}J_{z}| = |\epsilon^{n}| = \epsilon^{n}$ and therefore $\int_{B(0,1)}\eta(y)u_{m}(x-\epsilon y)dy = \int_{B(0, \epsilon)}\eta_{\epsilon}(\frac{z}{\epsilon})u_{m}(x-z)\epsilon^{n}dz$ but $u_{m}^{\epsilon}(x) = \int_{B(0,\epsilon)}\eta(y)u_{m}(x-y)dy$$\eta_{\epsilon}(x) := \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ Can you see where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @LucioD If $\det J_z =\epsilon^n$, then   $dy = (dy/dz)dz = \epsilon^{-n} \,dz$. Yes, it seems we have equality. Although I can't be sure that I read your mind correctly; you never said what $V$ was.

Comment: The $V$ is taken as the whole space. $f \in W^{1,p}(V)$ where $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$.